# jQuery datepicker posting the incorrect date

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using some javascript/jquery in the form of a datePicker to get the users input. I am then posting this data to a checkdate.php that will check to see if a booking has been made on that date, free/unavailable will be returned. However, the datepicker is posting a date value that is one day behind what the user is selected and I haven't a clue why! Code is as below:

```
       <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){

              $("#requestdates").hide();

              $("#from").datepicker({
                  dateFormat:'dd/mm/yy',

                  maxDate: "+2M +2D"
              });           

              $("#getBetween").on('click', function(e){
                      //page does not reload
                      e.preventDefault();
                     var start = $("#from").datepicker("getDate");
                      //console.log(start);
                     start = (new Date(start)).toISOString().substring(0,10);

                      console.log(start);      

                      var tutordata =  $("#tutor").val();
                      var userdata = $("#user").val();

                      console.log(tutordata);
                      console.log(userdata);

                      $.ajax({
                          //perform an ajax functions
                          url:"checkdate.php",
                          data: {datedata: start, tutorid: tutordata, userid: userdata},
                          type: 'POST',
                          success:function(data){
                              console.log(data);
                              $(".valid").html(data);
                              $("#requestdates").show();
                          }

                      }); 
              });

        });
        </script>
```

And...

```
 <div class="container pad">  
            <div class="row">
            <h2><strong>Make a booking:</strong></h2>

            <?php
            if (isset($_SESSION["jlewis13_id"])) {

                $posterid = $_SESSION["jlewis13_id"];

                echo "<div class='form-group'>

                <div id='results'></div>
                <div class='valid'></div>
            </div>
            <div class='col-md-6'>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    Book a session on: <input id='from' class='form-control' 
data-msg='Please enter date' data-rule='minlen:12' required/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button id='getBetween' class='btn btn-skin btn-lg btn- 
block'>Check Date</button>

            <button id='requestdates' class='btn btn-skin btn-lg btn- 
block'>Request Date</button>
            <input type='hidden' value='$id' id='tutor' name='tutor'>
            <input type='hidden' value='$posterid' id='user' name='user'>
        </div>";
            } else {
                echo "<h2>To make a booking, you must be signed in.</h2>";
            }
            ?>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Anyone got any ideas?

TIA

Comment: I think you'll find that it is the server that is interpreting the input incorrect. Have a look at the Chrome/Firefox Developer tools (press F12 to bring them up) and have a look at the data that is posted from the browser to the server. You'll be able to see exactly what is sent. I believe you'll see that the browser/JavaScript is sending it correctly. Your server will be the one that's probably removing hours, likely because of timezone differences (well, it thinks there is a difference)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have checked the developer console and the incorrect data is being sent. For instance, if I clicked on 11-04-2018, the console shows 10-04-2018

Comment: Is your system region settings set to the correct country/locale?

Comment: @ash - Yeah, my system is set to the correct date/time and country